# Android Native for beginners: Where can I find more about these types of syntax (java interface, inheritance and more)

Tags: java, android

I already had been introduced to basic java syntax, but I've just seen in android docs something new to me which my google skills have not helped too much.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview

```
class ListViewLoader : ListActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
{

    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    private lateinit var mAdapter: SimpleCursorAdapter

    //...
    val root: ViewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    // ...
```

Which is the name for this type of class declaration which do not make use of `extends` or `implement`?

And also the name of those type of var declarations.

Where can I find whether this is android specific or for all java flavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is not written in Java. It is written in Kotlin, another programming language available for Android developers.

The items that you cite are Kotlin syntax. That syntax is not unique to Android development, but it is not Java syntax.

On that page, where you see your sample code, you will see two tabs above that code, labeled "KOTLIN" and "JAVA". You can toggle the sample between the two languages.

Comment: I don't believe it was that! Sorry for being so stupid haha